crontab schedule on Alpine Linux runs on days it's not supposed to run on
I have a schedule in my personal crontab on an Alpine Linux 3.20 system that runs at 00:10 from Tuesdays to Sundays (i.e., all days of the week except Mondays):
10 0 * * 2-7  "$HOME/local/sbin/backup.sh" prune-daily

This appears to trigger on Mondays too.  Why?

Note that my initial report gave the symptoms as "Does not run on Sundays".  I misremembered what happened, sorry.  I have corrected the description of the symptoms after investigating them more thoroughly.  The crontab schedule is correct, as it was from the start.

Are you sure you're not using TempleOS? /s

@HashimAziz I am 100% certain that I am using Alpine Linux 3.20.

I made so many mistakes with cron syntax that I switched to using the ansible cron module for this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html . Wouldn't have helped in this case, though.

@serv-inc I think that I’m just too used to the Vixie Cron implementation and slightly ignorant of the fact that other cron daemons may have their own quirks. Cron schedule specifications are AFAIK not standardised.

@Kusalananda: interestingly enough, they seem to be standardized: https://man.openbsd.org/crontab.5 says "The crontab file format is compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (“POSIX.1”) specification. The behaviours described below are all extensions to that standard:
The day-of-week field may use 7 to represent Sunday.
[...]"

@serv-inc Ha! You’re right! And even more interestingly, the BusyBox 0-6 for the days is standard, while Vixie’s 7=Sunday is an extension (Edit: I didn’t read your full comment before checking for myself; I see now that you already mentioned this). Well, I live and learn it seems. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/crontab.html

@Kusalananda: thanks for the link to the POSIX spec! I was not aware where to find it online.

The familiar Vixie Cron daemon uses the integers 0 through 7 to designate the days of the week, from Sunday to Sunday (both 0 and 7 are Sunday).  A schedule with 2-7 in the day-of-week field would therefore run on Tuesdays, Wednesdays, ..., and Sundays.  Using 7 to designate Sundays is an extension to the POSIX standard for crontab.
If enabled, the default Cron daemon on Alpine Linux is not the Vixie Cron daemon but a minimal implementation built into BusyBox.
The BusyBox Cron daemon does not use the integer 7 for Sundays and only allows seven integers to designate the day-of-week, from 0 to 6, with 0 used for Sundays, as evident from its source code.
In conclusion, the crontab schedule needs to be modified to the following to still run on all days of the week apart from Mondays:
10 0 * * 0,2-6  "$HOME/local/sbin/backup.sh" prune-daily

Or, alternatively,
10 0 * * Tue-Sun  "$HOME/local/sbin/backup.sh" prune-daily


The reason the schedule is triggered every day when a day-of-week range ending in 7 is used is due to a loop in the code that tries to determine what days of the week a job with a range specification should be added to:
/*
 * fill array, using a failsafe is the easiest way to prevent
 * an endless loop
 */
{
    int s0 = 1;
    int failsafe = 1024;

    --n1;
    do {
        n1 = (n1 + 1) % modvalue;

        if (--s0 == 0) {
            ary[n1 % modvalue] = 1;
            s0 = skip;
        }
        if (--failsafe == 0) {
            goto err;
        }
    } while (n1 != n2);
}

The loop runs from the start of the range until the end, but increments using n1 = (n1 + 1) % modvalue (where n1 is the day-of-week number and modvalue is 7, for seven days).  Since that can't possibly reach 7 (it goes to a maximum of 6 and then wraps around to 0), it triggers a "failsafe", which terminates the loop after 1024 iterations.  By then, the job has been added to all days of the week (the elements 0 through 6 in the ary array have been set to 1).
Since the code handles single day value like 2 (Tuesday) and 3,4 (two single days, Wednesday and Thursday) as single value ranges (2-2 and 3-3,4-4 respectively), a single digit 7 in the day-of-week field would also cause the same issue.

If Tue-Sun works then does 2-0 also?

@hobbs That would work, but it looks really odd to me (I'm used to ranges running from low to high, and to weeks running from Monday to Sunday).

Wow, kudos on a really thorough answer. I would call it a bug in BusyBox -- that it not only silently differs from Vixie Cron behavior on 7, with no warning, but also triggers this weird behavior instead of ignoring it. I would consider reporting it as a bug, if it hasn't been noted before.

@GlennWillen As noted in the comments to the question, BusyBox’s non-support for 7=Sunday is POSIX compliant, so strictly speaking it’s not a bug but a surprising behaviour if all you know is the Vixie Cron implementation (in which 7=Sunday is an extension to the standard).  I’ll add a note about this in my answer in a few hours.

@Kusalananda yeah, it was a matter of curiosity :)

Certainly it makes sense to hew to POSIX, but it would be trivial to issue a warning, and I always prefer tools that are helpful vs. unhelpful in this sort of situation...
